# Get Session Data in Django Forms

Tags: django, django-sessions

Given a Django form, I have the following `save()` method:

```
def save(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data.get('name', None)

    user = User.objects.get(1) #I want the session user ID from here
```

So to do so I imported as so:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest as request
```

and in the above code I wrote

```
request.session.get('user_id') #for example
```

However, when run, Django throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'session'
```

Is there a better way to do this retrieval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just import the HttpRequest class and expect it to have the values from the current request. You need to actually pass in that current request from the view.

Comment: `def save(self, request)` and `form.save(request)` doest the trick!